# Compiz black background problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, compiz, opengl

After a reboot suddenly Compiz stopped showing the background and when I drag windows along it I get the following effect:

[image: ]]

(note at the left that the files on the desktop stand on the foreground)

If I go to the settings and disable OpenGL it stops doing this but that's not a solution. Already tried resetting settings (`rm -rf ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/*`) and uninstalling (with `apt-get purge`) compiz but it didn't help out.

What happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

May be this will be help you....  :)

First install dconf-tools...

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Then reset Unity and Compiz settings...

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

And Restart Unity...

```
setsid unity
```

If this will not help then try this...

**Edited Answer....**

Once you are booted up to the desktop... press `CTRL + ALT + F1`

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*
apt-get install nvidia-prime
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: @LuísLopes .... I edited my answer. So, please check it... it's working for you or not... ;)

Comment: it did not work as well. you maybe wondering why I took so long to answer. I switched to cinnamon as a workaround which worked well. weeks later (cinnamon broke and) I returned back and everything was fine (updates?) ..now it broke again (same issue). Please note that I didn't even had unity installed, I'm using cairo-dock on top of compiz. well back to cinnamon again. thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody have installed compiz reloaded (0.8) with all the awesome extensions, and the background (wallpaper, desktop) appears black, and all the windows movements generates crazy effects, you have to turn ON all the image compatibilities in the `ccsm` (Compiz Configuration Panel) like you can see in this screenshot:

[turn ON all the image compatibilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikvEN.png)

Now you can use compiz as you deserve.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.05

``````
 ./+o+-       nico@Auxiliar
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.0-48-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 1h 53m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 2257
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1280x1024
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: GNOME 
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: Compiz
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Adwaita
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: ubuntu-mono-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Ubuntu 11
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i3-4170 @ 4x 3.7GHz [27.8°C]
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 1694MiB / 5840MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````